# How exactly does a substring share its memory with the original string?

Tags: swift, string

The following code creates a string and then a substring from that string:

```
let x = "a quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"

let range = x.startIndex...x.index(x.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)
var substring = x[range]
```

From what I understand, `substring` should share its memory with the string `x`. But if I do:

```
substring.replaceSubrange(substring.startIndex...substring.startIndex, with: "t")

print(substring)
print(x)
```

I get the following output:

```
t quick
a quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

Which means that they don't share the same memory anymore.

So, how does the memory sharing thing work? Does the call to `replaceSubrange` make a defensive copy of the text "a quick" inside the `substring` object and then replace the first letter "a" with "t"?

Or is " quick" still shared with the original string `x`, but the new memory was allocated only for the first character "t"? As far as I know that shouldn't be possible, because arrays store their memory continuously.

So, at which point did `substring` stop sharing its memory with `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/substring), `Substring` instance is the result of slice of a string. It shares its storage with the original string which it is store inside this `SubString` not the original.

First, you need to know just like your example `x` is a String which is a value not a class. So it shares its memory with this `x` will and never happend.

When you create a `Substring` it automatically copy the value of your `x` which is `a quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog` into a type `Slice<String>` as `base` and return back to you a `Substring` which is `String.SubSequence` of this own `Slice<String>`. And this `base` share its storage with `Substring` and no connection with the original `x`

Because of that, when ever you change the value `x` not making the value of this `Slice<String>` change too.

Example like this

```swift
var x = "a quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" // your original string

let range = x.startIndex...x.index(x.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)
var substring = x[range] // copy your original and combine with start index and end index

print("first substring: ", substring) // your desire result
print("base of substring: ", substring.base) // the value of x when clone into when creating substring

x = "abcder" // changing value x

print("second substring: ", substring) // still the same
print("base of substring: ", substring.base) // still the same
```